# Pandas: Using DataFrame.apply() with Series.sum() function across columns of a dataframe is faster than calling DataFrame.sum(). Why?

Tags: python, pandas

I did not expect this result.  If anybody can shed some light on this it would be much appreciated.

### Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def test3():
    df["A"].sum()
    df["B"].sum()
    df["C"].sum()
    df["D"].sum()


def test4():
    df.sum(axis=0)

def test5():
    df.apply(lambda x: x.sum(), axis=0)


print(timeit.timeit(test3, number = 100))  
print(timeit.timeit(test4, number = 100))
print(timeit.timeit(test5, number = 100))
```

### Output

0.41974469999999997

0.8643757000000001

0.6898605

Comment: What result do you expect instead?

Comment: @Valentino I did not expect test4 to be slower than test5.  I thought it should be at least as fast as test5 because presumably the implementation of DataFrame.sum could be exactly what is written in test5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test 3 is operating as pd.Series, which are basically numpy.arrays with metadata. Numpy arrays are blazingly fast. test4 and test5 are operating at the dataframe level. Still fast, but not as fast as pd.Series.

Here's a fun experiment. Create a dataframe with lots to count. Must be two columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5000000,2), columns= list('ab'))
```

Now, let's make two similar, but different columns, the first is a dataframe.

```
type(df[['a']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

The second is a series.

```
type(df['a'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Both are the exact same column, just the first is a dataframe, and the second a series.

Now, let's see their performance:

DataFrame

```
%%time 
df[['a']].sum()
CPU times: user 108 ms, sys: 49.4 ms, total: 157 ms
Wall time: 68.8 ms
```

Series

```
%%time 
df['a'].sum()
CPU times: user 26.7 ms, sys: 17.9 ms, total: 44.6 ms
Wall time: 43.1 ms
```

That's a pretty significant different, the pd.Series is 4 times faster.

And finally, for reference, if we convert the series to a numpy array and run it...

```
arr = np.array(df['a'].values)
%%time
arr.sum()
CPU times: user 4.25 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 4.25 ms
Wall time: 3.34 ms
```

4.25 ms!!! When you want to really go fast with lost of data, try to get down to numpy.array, it will almost always win the day.

And this is a [good article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer run-out!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad you like. If appropriate please accept this as the correct answer? Thanks